# Floating DIV in pixels and DIV in percent (responzive design). Can't figure it out

Tags: html, css

I'm floating **DIV in pixels** and **DIV in percentage**. Which works just fine.

But whenever I use **clear: both** inside of **percentage DIV** rest of the content jumps down. But I have to use **clear:both** inside of it, because inside I'm floating another DIVs.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">

    <div style="width: 100px; height: 200px; background: blue; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="background: green;">
        aaa
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
        aaa
    </div>
</div>
```

- I tried float it by position: absolute. But this destroys rest of my web.
- I'm not sure about using calc() (not supported by all browsers)
- No javascript
- I don't have any other ideas

Comment: You're not making clear what is wrong with your current implementation, or what you would like to get. Also, please provide a [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can look at what you did so far.

Comment: Whenever I use clear: both inside of percentage DIV rest of the content jumps down. But I have to use it. Either clear it some other way or float it some other way, which allows clearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Clear:both`
doesn't allow any div to float either on right or left side.
try giving `height` property.

The desired output is not clear.

EDIT:

use

`<a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>`

use ' ' (single quotation marks) rather than " " after echo since / will end it.

EDIT 2:

```
<div style="width: 100%;">

<div style="width: 100px; height: 200px; background: blue; float: left;"></div>
<div style="background: green;width:100%;">
    <div style="background-color:red;width:100px;float:left;">
        Product 1
        <div style="">
            Header
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:red;width:100px;float:left;">
        Product 2
        <div style="">
            Header
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have menu (fixed width in pixels). And I have content DIV (in percent, width: auto). And they float next to each other. But when I use clear: both inside of content, rest of the content jumps under menu. And I'm asking how to prevent this. Provided code simulates my problem.

Comment: dont use clear since it doesnt allow anything to float alongside.

Comment: Content DIV contains eshop products. Which are floating next to each other. And if I want to add some header under it, I have to clear it first. Otherwise that header will float with the products! I just have to clear it. But how? If I clear it, it will destroy menu/content floating.

Comment: i will edit answer assuming that you want to have products floating next to each other and with headers or some content under it.Correct me if i am wrong.One more thing, kick clear thing out of your brain

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. But check this out. Now I will use clear both in your code. https://jsfiddle.net/47bt90ur/2/ And rest of the green content will jump under the menu! Which is the problem.

Comment: You can't do anything for that while using clear. I still unable to understand the requirement of clear after getting the desired output

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/47bt90ur/4/ Do you see the problem now? Motorbike H4 is floating next to products. And green background doesn't cover all height. That's why I want clear it before second H4.